# Why we have to say Keriat Shma on the bed in the Sukkah?

Tags: halacha, minhag, sukkah, shema, sukkot

It is known that on Passover night the custom is not to say  Keriat Shma on the bed since it is called Shimurim night - a night that is preserved from the 'bad winds' (Mazikim). We don't put a Mezuza on the Sukah and we are allowed to sleep alone since it protects us from 'bad winds' (Mazikim). So why isn't it the same as Passover night? Why do we have to say Keriat Shma on the bed in the Sukkah?

Comment: Great question! Note though that the sukkah is exempt from a mezuzah because it is a temporary dwelling, not because of the divine protection it recieves